# Make emacs lock display of the first line of a file

Tags: csv

How can I make Emacs always display the first line of a file which contains header information (such as a CSV) as I scroll down past where it would usually no longer be visible?

Comment: Making a new window just for the header line would work, except that often the number of columns in a csv is so large that it scrolls past the screen.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Make it a [**header line**](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Header-Lines.html).

A window can have a header line at the top. It does not scroll out of the window, but remains displayed at the top. I guess that's what you are asking for.

Comment: @wdkrnls If you use the [sx.el](https://github.com/vermiculus/sx.el/) package, you will notice they the key board shortcuts display on the top of the buffer is implemented using `header-line-format`: `("    " (:propertize "n p TAB" face mode-line-buffer-id) ": Navigate"
 "    " (:propertize "u d" face mode-line-buffer-id) ": Up/Down Vote"
 "    " (:propertize "c" face mode-line-buffer-id) ": Comment" "    "
 (:propertize "a" face mode-line-buffer-id) ": Answer" "    "
 (:propertize "e" face mode-line-buffer-id) ": Edit" "    "
 (:propertize "q" face mode-line-buffer-id) ": Quit")`.

Comment: `header-line-format` looks promising, but it doesn't really integrate well with `csv-mode` and especially with the `csv-align-fields` function. Even if it could, it doesn't hide the first line.

Comment: I wish there was a `tabular-data-mode` that read in text delimited data as an user editable form of `tabulated-list-mode`, which probably also uses the `header line` feature.

Answer (score 2):

You could also split the window.
`C-u 1 C-x 2`